# access files from s3 bucket on client side meteor.js

Tags: node.js, meteor, amazon-s3

So I am struggling getting images from an s3 bucket to show up client side in a meteor app. I am using aws-sdk node package. I am getting the objects in my console on the server side and if I change my bucket policy to public it works as well. The fact that the objects show up in the console on startup but are not showing on the client side make me think it is a meteor problem I am just having trouble finding good documentation on the subject.

server.js

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: Meteor.settings.AWS.S3.accessId,
    secretAccessKey: Meteor.settings.AWS.S3.secret
  });

  s3 = new AWS.S3({
    region: "<my-region>"
  });

  var params = {
    Bucket: "<my-bucket-name>"
  };

  s3.listObjects(
    params,
    Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(data);
    })
  );
})
```

Here is my bucket policy( when I set the resource to * it works but I want the resource set to a specific IAM account):

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy-some-number",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<current-iam-account-in>"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<current-iam-account-in>"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<current-iam-account-in>"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add the client code that is used to display the fetched  images?

Comment: @jankapunkt right now the code that displays the images is the s3 url that is saved in our db

Comment: I am referring to the code that receives this URL and renders the image using the front end rendering engine of your choice